# Should I delete all of my partitions while still running windows I want to do a complete install of just Ubuntu

Tags: partitioning

Tell me if I'm wrong on this as well delete all of my partitions will make my computer run faster while using just Ubuntu

Comment: No need one of the options when installing is replace everything with Ubuntu.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

It is very unlikely that you will notice any speed difference.

This will not affect the perceived speed of your system, for example ability to multi-task or watch high definition video.

The only thing that could potentially be affected are file reads and writes. However, since individual partitions are already contiguous on the hard drive, I doubt deleting other partitions would help.

Comment: Thank you very much! so Ubuntu will delete all my partitions if I choose in installation remove windows and do a exclusive Ubuntu install?

Comment: Although I've never actually chosen that option, I believe that is indeed what it should do. I would expect it to delete all your partitions (including windows and all of your data) and start entirely from scratch. You will likely end up with two partitions, one for Ubuntu, and one for swap.

Comment: I was very successful in installing Ubuntu exclusive I did have to teach myself how to manually add a swamp area but it does give me more stand in RAM in the event that I run out of ram or want to going to hibernation it probably also has lots of other things it can do but I don't know all of that yet